# how to display a message in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to debug the **ansible_hostname** variable in order to have the names of the different hosts to display.

unfortunately I am unable for the moment to display the value of the variable even the name I wrote in the task (:

```
- name: display variable 
  debug: 
    msg: "value variable  {{ ansible_hostname }}"
    verbosity: 4 
  tags:
     - attrest
```

do i ve to add a **parameters** in my **playbook** or in other files ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unable"?

Comment: `verbosity:4` means that the debug message will only be visible when you add `-vvvv` in your command

Answer (score 1):

```
msg: value variable  "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

Parenthesis to add in the playbook where variable is used

Comment: How is that different to what the OP wrote?

Comment: but i can write it on the **task** and not on the **playbook.yml** ?

Comment: There are multiple ways we can use var, two of them are

1. Create a role + add vars folders put a main.yml . declare a variable and reference it in task
 2. Create a var : directly in playbook and refer it in a task